Options on Futures, akuna question
From the below question, I am unsure why the option expiring in November is given by the January future. I thought it was a graphical issue, but it is supposed to look like it’s shifted to the right.
Can someone please help me understand how you can infer the November option is for the January future? Why must it be 2 to the right, rather than 1? It’s from the Akuna Options 101 course.



There are no November futures and there are no December futures, so what the heck could be the deliverable? It has to be a later month for which there exist futures. You answered a non-existent deliverable.

The general concept they are testing you on is that an 'option on a future' can be exercised to deliver a future which expires at the same time as the option or at a later date. The way they are testing you is with a trick question that will confuse some people, which is unfortunate and unfair.

@nbbo2 but why couldn’t it be the March future apart from the fact that the January future is the next future in the sequence?

Listed options are almost always written on the next futures expiry after the option expires. So a Nov option would be on Jan futures, a Feb option on Mar futures etc

ayamathss1: notice that the March future although it does exist is not one of the provided answers, and you are restricted to these 5 answers. I suppose June is a possible answer, but see river_rat's point as to the common practice on futures exchanges.
